# How to access (or switch between) tray icons with shortcut in windows?

Tags: windows, switch, notification-area

How to access (or switch between) tray icons with defined shortcuts in windows? I have many running programs which I cannot reach with alt-tab because they are not in taskbar - they are in tray. How do you reach those applications without a mouse? I heard of some tricky keys combination (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> and then find application with arrow keys), but it's ridiculous to use such long keys combination for such simple task. Is there any utility to manage switching like TaskSwitchXP for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>? Or maybe TaskSwitchXP has possibility to access applications in tray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[4t Tray Minimizer Free](http://www.4t-niagara.com/tray.html)** can do this and more.

[image]

> - various ways to minimize any application to the system tray;
> - ability to hide any application without showing tray icon;
> - **the customized hotkeys for minimizing, restoring, maximizing and
>     launching applications;**
> - ability to customize the minimizing behavior of your favorite
>     application;
> - quick hiding/showing the whole system tray.

You can [download it here](http://www.4t-niagara.com/tray.html). A free version as well as a paid version ($19.95) is available.

---

As for the key combination, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> 3 times to get to the tray. But I don't think you can switch between the apps in the tray like this, it only highlights time.

Answer (score 5):

Use **Windows + B** to access tray icons in Windows 7. To access Hidden tray icons press **Enter** after it. Use Arrow keys to nevigate between icons. Used a lot in Windows 7, But I have to check it for Windows XP

Comment: Also, you can filter your selection by entering the first letter of the application's title. Supposing you wanted to bring up `Network` dialog, it'd be `[Windows]/[Super]`+`[B]`, then `[N]` (repeated until the `Network` icon is selected) and then `[Enter]`